# How to run statements in reverse c#

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have a c# method that runs certain code blocks in a certain order. I want to pass a boolean parameter : "IsRunningInReverse" that will reverse the order in which the code blocks are run?

I could just create 2 private methods that just call the statements in normal and reverse order but I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this?

I was thinking about creating delegates (Action<>) and storing them in a List and then the boolean "IsRunningInReverse" would determine whether I'd run through the list in ascending or descending order but I don't know if that's the cleanest solution.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: A [mcve] would really help here.

Comment: In C#7.3, you can put the parens in front of the method name and it'll execute in reverse. This is done to simplify certain LINQ expressions. `e.(a.foo <= a)OrderBy`, for example.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Seriously? What are they planning for c# 9.0? writing lambda expressions up-side-down as well? That code seems so unreadable to me I'm not sure if that's because I'm getting older and it's harder for me to learn new tricks, or because it's just, well, backwards.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Well... not *real* seriously...

Comment: Thanks! for a minute there I thought I'm getting too old for this job :-)

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm still asking the duck about that but he doesn't answer

Comment: @Pac0 You have to ask him backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution seems fine to me.

Using `Action`s would be an idiomatic modern C# object wrapper for delegates, you can manipulate them easily.

To put them into a list is simple and will allow for what you want (reverse order), and even more (arbitrarily reorder them)

Maybe what might be more complicated and deserves some consideration is : would you need shared data ?

It should not be too difficult to handle this, but you would need a bit more structure (design some data sharing class for instance.

---

If you want to go further, once you feel more at ease with your solution, is maybe learn about [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) .

That would be a powerful tool to manipulate different operations / actions. Beware, though, there is a large learning gap, it is quite more complicated than a List of Actions. If you simple want to reverse operations, I would still deem your `List<Action>` idea much more *clean* because it is much more *simple* and *readable*. I just thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it:
Make your "steps" separate functions.
Make a dictionary of the tasks and the "rank".
Then just sort asc/desc depending on what you are after.

Comment: or an UGLY way is to use "switch" with a task#... and sort asc/desc

Comment: Why a dictionary? A simple List or array would be simpler and probably have better performance.

Comment: I agree personally I'd build a "rank" class or some such and just use the list object to store as well, but a dictionary is an easier route here.

Comment: @Trey If the only reason they're in the collection is for ordering, use an ordered collection and reverse it when needed. I don't see what a dictionary adds other than unnecessary complexity.

Comment: yep... not saying my way was the worlds greatest, just easy, and it answers the question.  There are a ton of ways to do this.  And frankly Ed, your answers are usually the cleanest. :-)